# Reading data from CSV file in c

Tags: c, csv

I am trying to read data from CSV file and want the output in certain format. I have about 200 lines of data with 7 variables.

With my code, I get the following output instead (this is just the 1st line; I should have 200 of them):

```
1880
3.9
0.91
115.7
4.1
45
0.03
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{   
    FILE *file = fopen("data.csv", "r");

    char buf[199]; 
    float V2, V3, V4,V5, V7;
    int V1, V6;

    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file))
    {  
        sscanf(buf,"%d, %f,%f,%f,%f,%d,%f", 
               &V1, &V2, &V3, &V4, &V5, &V6, &V7);

        printf("\n%d\n%f\n%f\n%f\n%f\n%d\n%f\n", V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

This code works and gives the output I mentioned above.

I want the output be like,

```
sample[0][0]= 1880;sample[0][1]= 3.9  ;sample[0][2]= 0.91;sample[0][3]= 115.7;sample[0][4]=   4.1 ;sample[0][5]=   45;sample[0][6]=  0.03
```

Comment: So you just need to change your `printf` call, I think?

Comment: What problem are you having with changing the printf format.  It seems pretty obvious to me which means there is some subtlety that you haven't explained.

Comment: It looks like you're going to need to count the lines as they come in, which isn't rocket science.  You're going to need to think about your print formatting; using `%f` will give you 6 decimal places each time.  You probably want `%g` instead.  If you want the data in an actual array, then you'll need to work on your data structures.  Note that an array will be all the same type (all `int` or all `float`); you won't be able to have column 0 and column 5 as `int` and the rest as `float`.  So, maybe you need a structure to represent each row instead?

Comment: Notice that your question is **not** about reading data from CSV file but "how to output tabular data in a specific format with row and column numbers"

Answer (score 1):

That's the output you got because that's the output you coded.

```
printf("\n%d\n%f\n%f\n%f\n%f\n%d\n%f\n", V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7);
```

To get the output you want you need two changes. First, you need to change what you're printing. Second, you need to keep a row count.

First, be sure to error check that your file opened.

```
FILE *file = fopen("data.csv", "r");
if( file == NULL ){
    perror("data.csv");
    exit(1);
}
```

We can keep a row count by using a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop. Note I bumped up the buffer size to 1k, there's no reason to be stingy when reading lines from a file.

```
char buf[1024]; 
for(
    int row = 0;
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file);
    row++
) {
```

Then we're sure to error check that we correctly parsed a line.

```
    int result = sscanf(buf,"%d, %f,%f,%f,%f,%d,%f", &V1, &V2, &V3, &V4, &V5, &V6, &V7);
    if( result != 7 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not parse line %d '%s'\n", row, buf);
        continue;
    }
```

And now we can print what you want. [As @Jonathan Leffler suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler), we use `%g` which is like `%f` but it clips off trailing zeros.

```
    printf("sample[%d][0]=%d; sample[%d][1]=%g; sample[%d][2]=%g;... and so on...\n", row, V1, row, V2, row, V3);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I was missing the row count part. That really helped and I got the output I wanted. Since I'm new to C programming, I was having hard time with formatting part.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make all V variables identical (float or int) because it will be used to fill the 2-dimensional array (1 array of course can only be defined as 1 type of data type). Here I will use the float data type for the 2-dimensional array. (I change your Vx variable to aray).

```
float V[7];
float sample[200][7];
int row, column;
row=column=0;

while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file))
{  
    sscanf(buf,"%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f", &V[0], &V[1], &V[2], &V[3], &V[4], &V[5], &V[6]);


    for(column=0; column<7; column++) sample[row][column]=V[column];
    printf("\nsmaple[%d][%d]: %f\nsmaple[%d][%d]: %f\nsmaple[%d][%d]: %f\nsmaple[%d][%d]: %f\nsmaple[%d][%d]: %f\nsmaple[%d][%d]: %f\nsmaple[%d][%d]: %f\n", row, column, V[0], row, column, V[1], row, column, V[2], row, column, V[3], row, column, V[4], row, column, V[5], row, column, V[6]);
    row++;
}
```

Comment: Since it's reading only 7 columns, 200 x 200 seems a waste. Would `sample[200][7]` be more appropriate? And can the `for` loop be omitted by passing `sample[row][0], sample[row][1], ...` into `scanf` and `printf`?

Comment: Why to you even need a one-dimensional array, let alone a two-domensional one?